# Cannot find index of corresponding date in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame with a `Date` column,

```
0      2021-12-13
1      2021-12-10
2      2021-12-09
3      2021-12-08
4      2021-12-07
          ...    
7990   1990-01-08
7991   1990-01-05
7992   1990-01-04
7993   1990-01-03
7994   1990-01-02
```

I am trying to find the index for a specific date in this DataFrame using the following code,

```
# import raw data into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data['dataset']['data'])
df.columns = data['dataset']['column_names']    
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# sample date to search for
sample_date = dt.date(2021,12,13)
print(sample_date)
# return index of sample date
date_index = df.index[df['Date'] == sample_date].tolist()
print(date_index)
```

The output of the program is,

```
2021-12-13
[]
```

I can't understand why. I have cast the `Date` column in the DataFrame to a `DateTime` and I'm doing a like-for-like comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your `Dataframe` with minimal samples. By changing the way that you can compare the `date` will work like this below.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021-12-13','2021-12-10','2021-12-09','2021-12-08']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
sample_date = dt.datetime.strptime('2021-12-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
date_index = df.index[df['Date'] == sample_date].tolist()
print(date_index)
```

output:

```
[0]
```

The search data was in the index number `0` of the `DataFrame`

Please let me know if this one has any issues